# How can I find library versions of an Android application?

Tags: android, kotlin, apk, deobfuscation, apktool

I'm pretty new on Android and I'm trying to understand the file system. I downloaded the apk file of an Android application and decoded it with apktool. Where is an android application listed versions of libraries? What's the easy way to find library versions of an app?

Sample libraries: OkHttp, Netty...

Comment: This has nothing to do with understanding the file system. An app may depend on 3rd party libraries that are all packed into the APK. You can try to reverse engineer these dependencies, and **apktool** is an invaluable in this task, but if the app uses even minimal obfuscation, this work is hard, and there is never a 100% guarantee that you don't miss some SDK.

Answer (score 0):

you can show it in

build.gradle(module:app) file

Comment: There is no such file :/